# Open links on the page in a new tab - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, markdown

How can we make every link on the page be opened in a new tab?

thus every link redirection will go to new tab. and website will be safe at it's place

We can do this,

```html
<a href="there_links.com" target="_blank">there_links.com</a>
```

But since user can add there own links in comments section which supports markdown.

Its hard to set `target="_blank"` on every link on a page. because these links will be popualted through `markdown` .

for example clicking [here](https://www.test.me/) will load page here itself. would prefer redirect.

Comment: How and where are you processing the markdown?

Comment: @charlietfl Its not limited to `markdown` but each and every link on the page.

Comment: Sure but if you are using vue it becomes important in order to loop through `<a>` with no target only after they exist

Comment: Semi-related, but if you're using _blank, you should also add rel=”noopener noreferrer” to prevent reverse-tabnabbing. See https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Reverse_Tabnabbing

Answer (score 1):

Select all the anchors in your page and then use `setAttribute` function to update the target attribute

```js
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank')

}
```

```html
<a href="there_links.com" target="_blank">link 1</a>
<a href="a.com">link 2</a>
<a href="there_links.com">link 3</a>
```

the above script could be set inside mounted hook in Vue component

Comment: Yes, but you could use inside a handler when you validate the markdown

Answer (score 1):

You can query `<a>` that have no target and set it something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a:not([target])').forEach(el => el.target = "_blank")
```

The critical part is running it only after you have processed the markdown into elements